# modifying class properties with John Resigs simple javascript inheritance

Tags: javascript

Currently I'm trying to use John Resigs Simple Javascript Inheritence library, this works great but when I try to modify default member variables, it seems to influence the prototype rather than only the instance:

http://jsfiddle.net/u2MWL/1/

As you can see, the events is of different length each time you create a new instance. Am I using the library in the wrong way or is this a known flaw? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are extending the class with `events: []`

Array (and `{}` object) variables are references. So by extending the class with an array, every instance of the class is going to have an `events` equal to the same referenced array.

To get around this you could do

```
var Test = Class.extend({
    events: null,

    init: function() {
        this.events = [];
        this.events.push(1);
        alert(this.events.length);
    },

    say: function(words) {

    }
});
```

This way, each time a class is initialized a new array (thus reference) is appointed to `events`. Not elegant, I know, but it should work.